# reusable ajax editor for model in asp.net mvc not going ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

ok so Im new to mvc. What Im making is a -create user form-. The UserViewModel has a branchcode property of type `long`. I want a small branch selector, where instead of a plain textbox for the code I have a textbox and a *check name* link, when clicked would return the name of the branch with some ajax.

So I made a branch selector and put it under Shared/EditorTemplates. Looks like this

```
@model long

<div class="editor-label">
    Branch ID: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Get Branch Name", MVC.Admin.Home.BranchDetail(Model),
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "BranchName", LoadingElementId = "loading" })
    <p id="loading" style="display: none">
        Loading...
    </p>
</div>
<div id="BranchName" class="editor-field">
</div>
```

I have the UIHint setup in the viewmodel so when I say EditFor(model.BranchName) it shows up perfectly like this:
[image]

My problems:

**1.** There is **no ajax!** When I click it goes the the url : http://localhost:1159/Admin/Home/BranchDetail?brcd=0 And then the URL throws an error because there is no BranchDetailsView anywhere.

This is what the controller looks like:

```
public virtual ActionResult BranchDetail(long brcd)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                //code to find branch
                if (br == null)
                {
                    return Content("No Branch Found");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Content(br.BranchName + "Circle: " + br.Circle);
                }
            }
            return View();//we should not be here.
        }
```

**2.** Another problem is, how do I get the AjaxLink to return what code what typed. If you notice the screenie, the url to the link has `brcd=0`. I want to send over the branch code to the controller! I tried `BeginRouteForm` with an input button inside the editor, but that ends up submitting the entire Create page form? Would that be the right way to do this?

Note: Im using T4MVC, also, Initially I forgot but I did reference both `microsoft.ajax.js` and `microsoft.mvc.ajax.js` in the create page.

---

**Update** : I managed to get this working with JQuery and it seems pretty nice and simple. However, I would really like to know how this kind of thing would be generally done with `Ajax.BeginForm` since Im learning MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using MVC 3, so you got to reference different scripts.

jquery-1.4.4.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

to begin with

and it seems that there is no way to pass client side data to @Ajax.ActionLink
So you might jump straight to implementing your lookup with a little help of jQuery.

Comment: Yes I do have jquery, jquery.validate.min, jquery.unobtrusive and the 2 ajax js files.

Comment: you need to reference them in your page for @Ajax.ActionLink to work

Comment: Yes yes! the _layout page has all the jquery files and the editor has the microsoft.ajax. What about using an ajax form?

Comment: microsoft.ajax should not be referenced.. it is there for legacy mvc2 projects.

Comment: So its just `microsoft.mvc.ajax`? Fortunately I got it to work with <3 jquery perfectly! but I'd like to get it working with `Ajax.BeginForm()`

Comment: no.. you don't reference any microsoft script.. just jquery and unobtrusive for that matter. And you won't be able to achieve what you want with @Ajax.ActionLink, because it does not provide a way to send data to server.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Correct, How would I do It with `Ajax.BeginFrom`? I updated the question.